What are the costs included for using AWS Billing data export functionality?
I want to use the AWS Billing data export feature, which exports and saves the billing cost for each service, in each region as per the granularity we configure.
I wanted to know, is there any pricing included for this export service, except the S3 data storage cost? I tried searching on the internet but didn't find any so far.

In terms of pricing for AWS Billing data export, there are no additional charges beyond the standard S3 data storage costs. AWS Billing data export is a feature provided by AWS to help customers manage and analyze their billing data more effectively. The exported billing data is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket of your choice, and you only pay for the storage usage of that bucket.
There are no separate charges for using the billing data export feature itself. However, keep in mind that you may incur charges for other AWS services that you use to analyze or process the exported billing data, such as Amazon Athena or Amazon Redshift.
